# How to put two RichTextBlock(Overflow) one after another vertically in RichTextColumns

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, richtextblock

As mentioned, I want to put two RichTextBlocks one after another vertically. My intention is to write manually the paragraphs of the first RichTextBlock, and I want the second RichTextBlock (that its content given programmatically) to start right after the first one, and I want that to happen so that the second RichTextBlock will overflow vertically to the next column.

The below snippet intended just so you could see the objects I'm using and has no any logical meaning.

```
<ScrollViewer 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        Padding="20">

            <RichTextBlock>
                <Paragraph><Run></Run></Paragraph>
            <RichTextBlock />

            <common:RichTextColumns>
                <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RichTextBlockOverflow Margin="80,0,0,0" Width="560">
                            <RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="4"/>
                            </RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                        </RichTextBlockOverflow>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                <RichTextBlock
                             htmlToXaml:Properties.Html="{Binding HtmlText}"
                             Name="RichTextBlockMy"
                             Margin="10,0,0,0"
                             Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}"
                             Width="560"/>
            </common:RichTextColumns>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: your code seems incorrect. There is no starting `<Run>` tag

Comment: but I told you that this code designated for you to know what objects I'm using, So the meaningless "Run" I put there is there to tell you that I want to put in this RichTextBlock some paragraphs manually later.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

XAML

```
<ScrollViewer 
    HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Padding="20">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <RichTextBlock>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="This is fixed RichTextBlock, after this it's RichTextBlock with RichTextColumns" FontSize="20"/>
                <LineBreak />
                <Run Text="{Binding FirstRtbText}" />
                <LineBreak />
                <Run Text="End of fixed RichTextBlock" FontSize="20" />
            </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>

            <common:RichTextColumns>
            <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RichTextBlockOverflow Margin="80,0,0,0" Width="560">
                        <RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="4"/>
                        </RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                    </RichTextBlockOverflow>
                </DataTemplate>
            </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
            <RichTextBlock 
                     common:Properties.Html="{Binding HtmlText}"
                     Name="RichTextBlockMy"
                     Margin="10,0,0,0"
                     Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}"
                     Width="560"/>
        </common:RichTextColumns>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

C#

```
    public string HtmlText { get; set; }
    public string FirstRtbText { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        FirstRtbText = @"<h1>Header One</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum <em>emphasised text</em> dolor sit amet, <strong>strong text</strong> 
consectetur adipisicing elit, <abbr title="""">abbreviated text</abbr> sed do eiusmod tempor 
<acronym title="""">acronym text</acronym> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
<q>quoted text</q> enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation <a href=""/"">link text</a> 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute <del>deleted text</del> 
<ins>inserted text</ins> irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat <code>code text</code> cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<blockquote>
<p>Blockquote. Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
</blockquote>";

            HtmlText = @"<h1>Header One</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum <em>emphasised text</em> dolor sit amet, <strong>strong text</strong> 
consectetur adipisicing elit, <abbr title="""">abbreviated text</abbr> sed do eiusmod tempor 
<acronym title="""">acronym text</acronym> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
<q>quoted text</q> enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation <a href=""/"">link text</a> 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute <del>deleted text</del> 
<ins>inserted text</ins> irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat <code>code text</code> cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<blockquote>
<p>Blockquote. Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
</blockquote>

<p><cite><a href=""/"">Cite author with link text</a></cite>, 2008</p>

<h2>Header 2</h2>

<p>Extended paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<ol>
<li>Ordered list</li>
<li>Item 2 Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
<li>Item 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</ol>

<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
anim id est laborum.</p>

<h3>Header 3</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<ul>
<li>Unordered list</li>
<li>Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</ul>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<pre><code>pre and code pair{
display:block;
line-height:1.833em;
border-top:0.083em solid #200;
}</code></pre>

<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit 
anim id est laborum.</p>

<h4>Header 4</h4>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<dl>
<dt>Definition list</dt>
<dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd>
<dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt>
<dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd>
<dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt>
<dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd>
<dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt>
<dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd>
</dl>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<table summary=""Table summary"">
<caption>Table Caption</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Content</td><td>1</td><td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content</td><td>2</td><td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content</td><td>3</td><td>c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content</td><td>4</td><td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content</td><td>5</td><td>e</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content</td><td>6</td><td>f</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<address>Author text</address>
";

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
```

Comment: I see you put there horizontal StackPanel, and right away I can tell that this is not what I want. I want the second RichTextBlock to appear below the first one, and when the content of the second RichTextBlock become to its end in the first column, it overflows to the second column (I want the second column to start from the starting y position of the first RichTextBlock...

Comment: Then, you can use single `RichTextBlock` and set it's property with static + dynamic text. You can also use `WrapPanel` instead of `StackPanel`

Comment: The idea of "static + dynamic text" is what I'm doing now, but I want to write the static content in the Xaml editor window without needing to copy it to the code-behind.

Comment: You can't do that in XAML, because your dynamic text is generated via binding. So you may use converter to attach static text to dynamic and then bind the text.